# Make Emission Gradient local

Tags: materials, node-editor, lighting, emission

I have this sort of sci-fi scene with ambient emission lights. I would like to have a gradient for each of them. Somehow my setup creates a gradient over the entire image rather than localized for each plane that emits. How would I have to change my setup in the node editor to get both emissions upper and lower to have a gradient in Z?

Thank you very much in advance!
Marlon

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hello :). Just to make sure - both your planes are one object?

Comment: Hey, they are one object but different planes that I assigned the material to. Would it help to make them different objects?

Comment: When they're one object, you need to use UV mapping. When they're separate, it'll work right away :).

Comment: Yep, that worked, as simple as that. I made it separate objects. Thank you!! ;)

Answer (score 2):

> When they're one object, you need to use UV mapping. When they're
> separate, it'll work right away :). – Jachym Michal 30 mins ago

Making the planes separate objects was the solution (or working with UVs).